# Can Intellij import all jars under a directory as libraries?

Tags: intellij-idea, bazel-java

IntelliJ (2021.2.2) recently stopped recognizing all external symbols in my codebase. Its a bazel project and I have the bazel plugin installed. The only way I have managed to import a jar file is by `File -> Project Structure -> Libraries`. Click the `+` and navigate to `<project root>/bazel-java/external/` then following the directories all the way down to the jar which I then import. I hit apply and IntelliJ recognizes it.

The project has a huge number of dependencies so this would take many hours. IntelliJ used to handle all this for me. I have no idea what happened, but I think it coincided with the Mac Sonoma update. Is there an option for intellij to automatically detect which dependencies are in my `java_library` bazel target and add them to IntelliJ?